# Multipass totally broken on MacOS & multipassd error logs

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, amd-gpu, multipass, qmutex

The com.canonical.multipassd service is constantly logging errors on my Mac and multipass won't work at all, even after reinstalling, rebooting, and updating my Mac.

In an attempt to use my GPU in a Linux VM through multipass, I tried to install the AMDGPU driver for my card (Radeon Pro 5300 4GB). I had installed multipass through brew and made some progress, but the `./amdgpu-install` process was returning various errors as a result of missing dependencies. Having started to resolve the missing dependencies, in an attempt to build the driver again, the build just stopped halfway through and I couldn't terminate the process or get the VM to respond at all (didn't take a screenshot sorry).

Because of this, I closed the VM shell and tried to get multipass to shut down the VM. Multipass stopped responding altogether - the application just spun, and it didn't respond at all in terminal. I force quit multipass in Activity Monitor. That still didn't fix it, so I (somewhat stupidly) force quit 'hyperkit' and 'multipassd'. This is where everything went really wrong.

Having force quit 'multipassd', I tried to re-open multipass, but it returned the error below

```
list failed: cannot connect to the multipass socket
Please ensure multipassd is running and '/var/run/multipass_socket' is accessible
```

I looked this up and tried a few suggested solutions. I uninstalled multipass with Brew. I deleted the application, and reinstalled with brew. I also tried `brew remove multipass`, and tried installing using the .pkg from the multipass website. When that didn't fix it, I restarted my computer and reset NVRAM on startup. That also didn't make a difference, so I have just updated my Mac to MacOS 11.4, and it is still not fixed.

The console logs suggest that `multipassd` is still doing something, as it is continually logging in the system.log:

```
May 26 09:39:15 <myName> com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.canonical.multipassd[2131]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
May 26 09:39:15 <myName> com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.canonical.multipassd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

In the multipass log, this message is also being generated about once every 10 seconds:

```
[error] [daemon] Caught an unhandled exception: Invalid MAC address 
[warning] [Qt] QMutex: destroying locked mutex
```

These messages are being generated even after resetting NVRAM and rebooting. I think they're the cause of my issue launching multipass, but I haven't found any solution to stop them, and I can't identify any process that is still running related to multipass. As far as brew is concerned, multipass is not installed, but it's logs are still filling up...

Happy to provide console or terminal output if needed - nothing else on my Mac seems to be broken, I just can't use multipass now. I do have a time machine backup, so if that is guaranteed to fix it, I might just resort to the backup, but I'm not sure that would necessarily fix it, and I would rather find an alternative solution.

As this has probably made clear, I'm very new to Linux and VMs... any solutions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same here. Attempted to install using cloud-init and same result (multipass stopped responding). Attempted to stop and purge the instance and now getting the same socket error as you.

Answer (score 11):

Fixed it!! I hadn't properly uninstalled it - the 'proper' uninstall script can be run using

```
sudo sh "/Library/Application Support/com.canonical.multipass/uninstall.sh"
```

Reinstalling multipass after running this command worked fine.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks! I also ran `brew uninstall --zap multipass` to destroy all data, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it

```
$ brew uninstall multipass
# or
$ brew uninstall --zap multipass # to destroy all data, too
```